# can audio from direction speakers be recorded with a smartphone?

Tags: audio, recording

I wanted to know if directional speakers can be recorded by a smartphone and if not how to record them.

Comment: In short, if you can hear it, so can your phone. How *good* the recording will be is equal to how well you or the phone can hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but don‘t expect high-quality results.

The best overall result will be obtained from having professionals recording the audio and sending it to your mobile device as mp3 or similar.

As do-it-„yourself“ you need electrical access to the analog output, ie. mixed-down, audio signal, convert it via an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter, i.e. audio interface). Next you need some external components so your mobile device can access and use the digital data stream.